# Populate new NSPersistentDocuments with seed objects / Discard changes on close

Tags: cocoa, nsundomanager, nspersistentdocument

Here's my issue:

I have a document-based application, all written using Core Data. When a new document is created (on app start, or using doing File > New, or Cmd+N), I need this document to be populated with initial seed objects. Let's say my document is a notebook, so I want new document to contain an empty note when created.
So I innocently insert my objects (`-[NSEntityDescription initWithEntity: insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`), and it works.

My issue here, is that the document appears to be *edited* right after being opened. Which is a terrible UX. Moreover, when closing this document without adding any further changes, the user is prompted to save it (super bothering!).

So what I tried so far to fix this problem, is setting the actions as *discardable* on my undo-manager (`-[NSUndoManager setActionIsDiscardable:]` to `YES` on `[myDocument undoManager]`). But it doesn't change anything.

To debug, I overrode `-[NSDocument isDocumentEdited]` and always returned `NO`. It fixes partially the issue. Of course, I don't want to deal with that stuff, I guess it should be fixed on the undo-manager/persistent document/managed object context side.

Anyone faced the same issue?

Thank you all very much!

Comment: I assume you are using NSPersistentDocument, if so then new files get created in memory so the user has to save to a file name before closing the document or everything gets lost. Also there is a specific method that gets called which is specifically for you to set up initial data. It only gets called on new documents. I don't recall what it is but I can look it up if you need it. Exactly what issue are you wanting to address?

Comment: Thanks :) I actually couldn't find this magic method that allows to setup initial data. That's exactly what I was trying to do: make new documents come with some seed data. I think I found a way using the `NSUndoManager`. I'll post an answer on that. If you recall this method, please let me know! Thanks. Micha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a way to do using the undo manager's `removeAllActions`:

```
- (id)initWithType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError`
{
    // Add your seed data in Core Data

    // Erase all actions to make the document appear as new
    [[self undoManager] removeAllActions];
}
```

It fixes all my issues, allow the document to be closed without being prompted to save, not showing the *Edited* menu on the title and not allowing users to undo the seed insertion actions.

Comment: The initWithType method above is the one I was referring to.

Comment: Yeah, but even if you add your seed objects inside this method, it will pollute your undo stack. That's why I had to come up with that `removeAllActions`. Thanks, though!